# Basic ConstraintLayout (Toolbar, fragment container, and bottom nav)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm adapting to Kotlin and ConstraintLayouts for Android.  I'm trying to have a simple layout that has a toolbar and a bottom navigation view.

Here is my current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Unfortunately, I'm misunderstanding something and cannot seem to get the fragment container to fill the space between the toolbar and the bottom navigation.

Can someone steer me in the correct direction?

Comment: Sorry!  I'm rewriting it in ruby on rails and it's taken quite some time to get to feature parity...also was going to move to an AWS or Azure stack :)  Thanks for reminding me to update my website url to my github thought!

Comment: Same to you my friend!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Height in your fragment container needs to be 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT".

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

You can look it up here [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).

It should be

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"/>
```

Comment: *sigh* Thank you...I knew it was something simple and tiny

Comment: I can't believe I wasted an hour on that...how silly

Comment: Working solution android:layout_height="0dp" saved time!

Comment: Thanks, change match_parent to 0dp is working

Answer (score -1):

This work with the layout I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/buttom_navigation"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Attaching the screenshot with the answer.

[image: Screenshot of the sample]